# Flask on Ubuntu Apache / Error 404 requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: python, ubuntu, flask

I use the following tutorial to set up Flask framework on Ubuntu
[How To Deploy a Flask Application on an Ubuntu VPS](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-flask-application-on-an-ubuntu-vps)

And I change the configure to the following statement, which located /etc/apache2/sites-available/FlaskApp.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName 192.168.0.1
        WSGIScriptAlias /testFlask /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi
        <Directory /var/www/FlaskApp/>
            Options FollowsymLinks
            AllowOverride None
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        LogLevel warn
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Finally, I used the url (http://196.168.0.1/testFlask) to check browser if it is running and I got  404 requested URL was not found on this server.
Can anyone give some idea? Thank you!

Comment: This could be more in the scope of Server Fault forum. But could https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/deploying/wsgi-standalone/ this documentation give any help.

Comment: And what do you have in Apache error log? There may be hints what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

You have your Apache conf in /etc/apache2/sites-available. But do you have linked it to /etc/apache2/sites-enabled. If not, that config does nothing.